# My jQuery code isn't working with WebStorm, but it is working with CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webstorm

I'm trying to make it so when I click a button it autoscrolls down using jQuery. It would look a lot better than a regular html jump. However, the code is only working on my CodePen/its exports, but not from anything through my WebStorm.

I've made sure to add the library for jQuery and added the script call. I know the library is added because it doesn't show squiggly's under the `$` anymore, but the code still isn't functioning correctly. The script call is there -- definitely, because it works with CodePen using the exact same (copied and pasted) code.

HTML:

```html
<script
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
            crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>

    <script> src="js/main.js>" </script>
```

JS:

```js
//Animate Smooth Scroll
$('#view-work').on('click',function() {
    const images = $('#images').position().top;

    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: images
        },
        900
    );
});
```

Full: https://codepen.io/at-lowdesu/pen/LKJKLr

I'm expecting it autoscroll like it does on CodePen, but through my WebStorm IDE and its exports.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I wasn't using the script call correctly.  `<script> src="js/main.js>" </script>` should be `<script src="js/main.js"> </script>`